# Jquery scrollTop not working with slideToggle and hidden div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, slidetoggle, scrolltop

I have a div hidden and when a link is clicked it toggles the content to slide out. Unfortunately I cannot get it to scroll down to the Top of the div when it is shown at the very bottom of the page. I have accomplished this with regular javascript, but I want it done with Jquery instead.

Jquery:

```
// Toggle Terms
$('.toggleTerms').click(function(){
$('#displayTerms').slideToggle("slow", function(){
    if($('#displayTerms').is(":visible")){
        $('#displayTerms').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#displayTerms').position().top
        }, "slow"
    )}
});
```

});

Link:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="toggleTerms">Terms</a>
```

Content:

```
<div id="displayTerms" style="display:none; overflow:hidden;">The Terms</div>
```

Btw, it opens and closes just fine. Above is what I have so far.

Comment: If you want to scroll *the page*, try `$(document).animate` instead.

Comment: I had that, it does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Nick Simone for getting me closer. The Answer is;

```
// Toggle Terms
$('.toggleTerms').click(function(){
$('#displayTerms').slideToggle("slow", function(){
    if($('#displayTerms').is(":visible")){
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $('#displayTerms').offset().top});
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/GDtHJ/

Here I'm animating the body's scroll position instead of #displayTerms - because we want the body's position to move to to #displayTerms's top.

Hope this helps.

oh you may want to resize your browser to make sure it has a scroll window on the bottom right pane in jsfiddle - otherwise you wont see it scroll :P

Comment: thank you for your attempt to remedy the issue, but it does not jump down to your target. The window only expands but not "scrollTo" that div.

Comment: My last one worked for me in FF and chrome but not IE. edited it and it now works in all 3.

Comment: i got your code to work BUT with scrollTop: $('#displayTerms').offset().top